# Understanding the 'directive' paradigm in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have been thinking about directives in Angularjs like user controls in ASP.Net, and perhaps I have it wrong.

A user control lets you encapsulate a bunch of functionality into a widget that can be dropped into any page anywhere. The parent page doesn't have to provide anything to the widget. I am having trouble getting directives to do anything close to that. Suppose that I have an app where, once the user has logged in I hang onto the first/last name of the user in a global variable somewhere. Now, I want to create a directive called 'loggedinuser' and drop it into any page I want. It will render a simple div with the name of the logged in user pulled from that global variable. How do I do that without having to have the controller pass that information into the directive? I want the usage of the directive in my view to look as simple as 
    <loggedinuser/>

Is this possible?

Comment: do not create an isolated scope in your directive and look for the needed variable in the scope that is passed to your directive's `link` function. or if you create an isolated scope then look for the variables in the parent scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can roughly sum up what a directive is as "something that encapsulates a bunch of functionality into a widget that can be dropped into any page anywhere", but there's more to it than that. A directive is a way to extend HTML by creating new tags, allowing you to write more expressive markup. For instance, instead of writing a `<div>` and a bunch of `<li>` tags in order to create a rating control, you could wrap it up with a new `<rating>` tag. Or, instead of lots of `<div>`s, and `<span>`s and whatnot to create a tabbed interface, you could implement a pair of directives, say, `<tab>` and `<tab-page>`, and use them like this:

```
<tab>
  <tab-page title="Tab 1"> tab content goes here </tab-page>
  <tab-page title="Tab 2"> tab content goes here </tab-page>
</tab>
```

That's the truly power of directives, to enhance HTML. And that doesn't mean that you should only create "generic" directives; you can and should make components specific to your application. So, back to your question, you could implement a `<loggedinuser>` tag to display the name of the logged user without requiring a controller to provide it with the information. But you definitely shouldn't rely on a global variable for that. The Angular way to do it would be make use of a service to store that information, and inject it into the directive:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, userInfo) {
  $scope.logIn = function() {
    userInfo.logIn('Walter White');
  };

  $scope.logOut = function() {
    userInfo.logOut();
  };
});

app.service('userInfo', function() {
  this.username = ''
  this.logIn = function(username) {
    this.username = username;
  };
  this.logOut = function() {
    this.username = '';
  };
});

app.directive('loggedinUser', function(userInfo) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E', 
    scope: true,
    template: '<h1>{{ userInfo.username }}</h1>',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.userInfo = userInfo;
    }
  };
});
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yslizIzzaYM9Tsp8xX6Z?p=preview).

The [Angular dev guide on directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) is a must-go place if you want to start creating powerful, reusable directives.

Comment: This is a great answer and very much what I was looking for. Thanks! 

A follow-up question I have is: let's say something happens on the view where this directive is placed - perhaps the user clicks on something that causes a log out - and I want the directive to update and display new text. But, no navigation is happening to another view, which I presume means the controller function on the directive will not be rerun, so I need the directive to react to an event somehow. How could I set this up?

Comment: No problem, man. Glad I could help. :) The directive's controller won't run again, but the interpolation added to the directive's template - the `{{ user.name }}` part - will be re-evaluated and its value will be updated. To understand it better, take a look [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope). I'll updated my answer to illustrate that.

Comment: Just to be clear, suppose my loggedinuser directive is placed in my index.html file so that it appears in the header above every view. Initially, there is no logged in user to show, so it will hide itself. But, upon navigating to my login view and doing a login via a web service, I want that directive to update (and show) itself with the name of my user. Since the controller of the directive is only run once, what is the mechanism that allows the scope of the directive to be updated? I believe that is the piece I am missing.

Comment: When you write `{{ }}` within a view, Angular creates a "watcher" that listens to the expression between the curly braces and re-evaluates it  every time the expression's value changes. That's done automatically for Angular expressions, but you can do it yourself by calling `$scope.$watch` if you need to monitor some complex changes. [This page](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts) has more information on how Angular keeps everything up-to-date.

Comment: Yup I get that. However, the link I am missing is: how do I make $scope.userInfo change?? The controller only runs once! In your example the logged in user is "Walter White". Let's say, based on some other action in the app, that changes to "Joe Public". How does this directive know about it?

Comment: Within directive's controller, the `userInfo` *service* is assigned to the `userInfo` *property* of the directive's scope, and the template is bound to the `userInfo.username` property. So, every time you change that property on the service, the directive knows about it because of the watcher Angular has created for the `{{userInfo.username}}` expression. I'm sorry I haven't been able to make myself clear. We can continue this discussion in chat if you like to.

Comment: Sure! I would really appreciate that. I'm not sure how chat works on stackoverflow. Do we do that through this site, or exchange contact info?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38501/discussion-between-kevin-macdonald-and-michael-benford)